# Java: Could not initialize class

Tags: java

I have a JAR file named `Appstome.jar`.

In two machines, I run the file successfully:

```
java -jar Appstome.jar
```

However, in a third machine with the same Java JRE, I get the following error:

```
Could not initialize class org.appstome.platform.SodiumKt
$ java.io.EOFException
<correct output>
```

I can see that the JAR file contains the referred class:

```
$ unzip -t /usr/local/bin/Appstome.jar | grep Sodium
    testing: org/appstome/platform/SodiumKt.class   OK
    testing: com/goterl/lazycode/lazysodium/SodiumJava.class   OK
    testing: com/goterl/lazycode/lazysodium/LazySodium.class   OK
    testing: com/goterl/lazycode/lazysodium/LazySodium$1.class   OK
    testing: com/goterl/lazycode/lazysodium/exceptions/SodiumException.class   OK
    testing: com/goterl/lazycode/lazysodium/Sodium.class   OK
    testing: com/goterl/lazycode/lazysodium/LazySodiumJava.class   OK
```

The working machines are local laptops running Ubuntu.
The third machine is in a remote server running an older Linux:

```
Linux version 3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64 (builder@kbuilder.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Mon Jul 16 16:29:36 UTC 2018
```

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: How does the constructor look for the failing class?

Comment: `val lazySodium: LazySodiumJava = LazySodiumJava(SodiumJava())`

Comment: The class just initializes a global variable (Kotlin code).

Comment: Thank you! The OS library is not installed.

Comment: What OS library??

Comment: libsodium was missing there

Comment: I would suggest you wrap the initializing step in your code, so this exception is caught and present a more informative message to the future you or others running this software.